# what will happen if app enters foreground during background fetch in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using silent push to fetch data in the background using the method below

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
{
  // background fetch process
}
```

iOS provides a time limit of 30 seconds to finish my operation and call the completionHandler. Consider that I am in the middle of background fetch and before it gets completed, the user launches my app by clicking on its icon.

What should I do in the above situation. Should I call `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);` in the foreground, terminate the background process or  how should I handle this  case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just continue your background job, and call `completionHandler` when it finishes.
iOS will handle it for you.

Otherwise, the logic of handling such cases will become very complex.